# VR: How to form hands around object they are holding in Unreal?

Tags: virtual-reality, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a VR project in Unreal and I'd like my player hands to form to certain objects whenever the user grabs them. (I.e. the way our hands work) Unfortunately, I haven't really found any examples online of others doing this.

For example, I'd like when the user picks up say a hand held tool like a hammer that the hand would wrap around the handle. When the user grabs a basketball the hand shouldn't be closed but, expanded like a you would if you were to palm a basketball in real life.

I haven't done a lot of testing with this but, I'm pretty sure since the hands are based off of a Animation Blueprint that they simply ignore collisions and follow the animation.

I guess the simplest solution would probably be based off of collision where the hand plays an animation and as the fingers of the hand wrap around the object they stop at that position where they collide with the object in question. If it is even possible that is.

Comment: Bumping this, its pretty important.

Comment: Line traces (ray casts) to determine animation axis input per-bone?

Comment: Can you expand upon that idea?

Comment: For each finger joint, do a ray cast (or even better a sphere cast) to find how far in it should go.